# My vue component watcher isn't pulling new data from Inertia prop

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Vue component and I'm trying to get the data displayed to update automatically with a watcher. The data is present but I have to reload the page for the changes to be seen, the data isn't updated in real-time.

I have been reading the Vue and Inertia docs but I can't see why it isn't working.

I am using Vue 3, InertiaJS and Laravel.

```
<template>
    <AppLayout title="Updated Automatically Example">
        <div v-for="fruit in fruits" class="text-sm">
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <img :src="fruit.image_url" :alt="fruit.name"
                     class="w-10 h-10 object-cover border border-gray-800 overflow-hidden">
                <div class="font-medium dark:text-white">
                    {{ fruit.name }} - {{ fruit.stock }} - ${{ fruit.price }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import {defineProps, ref, watch} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
    fruits: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
});

const fruits = ref(props.fruits);

watch(() => props.fruits, (newFruits) => {
    fruits.value = newFruits;
    console.log('New information has been retrieved from the database.');
}, { deep: true, immediate: true });
</script>
```

Here's my controller method too, which is being passed to the component.

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        $fruits = Fruit::all();

        return Inertia::render('UpdatedAutomatically', [
            'fruits' => $fruits,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You would need to update the data request from the laravel backend to update the data in vue.